# How should I pass props

Tags: reactjs

The error doesn't go off.
The codes look seem correct.

I looked up the way to write to pass the array to function.

```
class DebugTest extends Component<ParentHoge, {}>
{
  render(){
    return (
      <ComponentTest {...this.props.hongkong} />
    );
  }
}
let ComponentTest = (props: { hongkong: HongKong }) => {

     };

    type ParentHoge = {
      kind: 'Ready'    
    hogex: Hoge   
  hongkong:HongKong[]
}
class Hoge { }

type HongKong = {
  kind: 'HongKong'
  value: string 
}
`
```

Comment: hard to read this code

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

import React , {Component} from 'react';

```
class DebugTest extends Component<ParentHoge, {}>
{
    render(){
        return (
            <ComponentTest {...this.props.hongkong} />
        );
    }
}

class Hoge { }

type HongKong = {
    kind: 'HongKong',
    value: string
}


let ComponentTest = (props) => {
    type ParentHoge = {
        kind: 'Ready',
        hogex: Hoge,
        hongkong:HongKong[],
        spmething: props.something
    }
};
```

If you are using intellij then press ctl+alt+s then settings will be open. Under

setting-> Language & Framework -> JavaScript

You will see the JavaScript language version select it as FLow then save. Then IDE will help you finding syntex error